# Webforms meta tag error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
<meta name="keywords" content='<asp:Literal ID="litMetaKeywords" runat="server" />'/>
<meta name="description" content='<asp:Literal ID="litMetaDescription" runat="server" />'/>
```

I have found the above code in a Web App I am working on. I am getting the following error

```
The name 'litMetaDescription' does not exist in the current context
```

And the same for `litMetaKeywords`. If the asp:literal was not in this meta tag the code would be working. What is a meta tag? Whats its use? Is it what is causing my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting `<asp:Literal>` tag inside `content` attribute won't make it accessible from the code behind. You can use a combination of protected variables and inline code instead.

Code behind:

```
protected string MetaKeywords;
protected string MetaDescription;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MetaKeywords = "values for meta keywords";
    MetaDescription = "values for meta description";
}
```

aspx:

```
<meta name="keywords" content='<%= MetaKeywords %>'/>
<meta name="description" content='<%= MetaDescription %>'/>
```

For more information about HTML meta tags, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp).

Comment: I would also mention that ASP.NET server controls cannot be placed outside `form` tag in `.aspx` markup.